# How can add question from XML file into a list type

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Hi i want to try to put my atribute from xml file into a list data structure. But i don't have ideea how to make this... I try to create a class, but i don't know how can i implement my query in list This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace Lista
{
        class Program
        {
                List<QuestionList> test = new List<QuestionList>();
                static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                        var xml = XDocument.Load("questions.xml");
                        var query = from index in xml.Descendants("question")
                                    where (string)index.Attribute("TypeQuestion") == "eazy"
                                    select index;

                        foreach(var x in query)
                        {
                                Console.WriteLine($"{x}");
                        }
                }
                class QuestionList
                {
                        public string QuestionName;
                        public string answers;
                        public string rightIndex;
                        public string TypeQuestion;

                }
        }
}
```

xml file:

```
<QuestionsList>
            <question>
                <name>Question 1</name>
                <answers>a1,a2,a3,a4</answers>
                <rightIndex>3</rightIndex>
                <TypeQuestion>eazy</TypeQuestion>
            </question>
            <question>
                <name>Question 2</name>
                <answers>a1,a2,a3,a4</answers>
                <rightIndex>3,4</rightIndex>
                <TypeQuestion>eazy</TypeQuestion>
            </question>
            <question>
                <name>Question 3</name>
                <answers>a1,a2,a3,a4</answers>
                <rightIndex>1</rightIndex>
                <TypeQuestion>eazy</TypeQuestion>
            </question>
            <question>
                <name>Question 4</name>
                <answers>a1,a2,a3,a4</answers>
                <rightIndex>2</rightIndex>
                <TypeQuestion>mediu</TypeQuestion>
            </question>
            <question>
                <name>Question 5</name>
                <answers>a1,a2,a3,a4</answers>
                <rightIndex>2,4</rightIndex>
                <TypeQuestion>mediu</TypeQuestion>
            </question>
            <question>
                <name>Question 6</name>
                <answers>a1,a2,a3,a4,a5</answers>
                <rightIndex>5</rightIndex>
                <TypeQuestion>mediu</TypeQuestion>
            </question>
            <question>
                <name>Question 7</name>
                <answers>a1,a2</answers>
                <rightIndex>1</rightIndex>
                <TypeQuestion>mediu</TypeQuestion>
            </question>
        </QuestionsList>
```

If i try :

```
var xml = XDocument.Load("questions.xml");
var query = from index in xml.Descendants("question")
            select index;

foreach(var x in query)
{
        Console.WriteLine($"{x}");
}
```

I get content but if i try to select all question how has TypeQuestion "eazy" don't work.

Comment: Change Attribute to Element : where (string)index.Element("TypeQuestion") == "eazy"

Comment: @jdweng Ok it's work, now i want to put my attribute in list. Can you tell me please, how can i do that?

Comment: @ClaudiuAndries: "My attribute"? What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: i get this: https://pastebin.com/g1D6TDVm , i want to add in my list. I have x.Element("name") but i get <name>Question1</Question>, but i want to add just Question1

Comment: @ClaudiuAndries: I still don't understand what you want to add. There is already a "question1" in the XML.

Comment: Just add parenthesis to your query (from ......select index).ToList();

Comment: @ClaudiuAndries: Do you mean `x.Element("name").Value`?

Answer (score 0):

`<TypeQuestion>` is an element and not an attribute:

```
var query = from index in xml.Descendants("question")
            where (string)index.Element("TypeQuestion") == "eazy"
            select index;
```

And to get the name of the question from the `XElement` it's `x.Element("name").Value`.

Comment: @ClaudiuAndries: Does this answer your question or what's left to it?